# how validation can be done on rails using wicked gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

:fname, :lname, :email, :mob,  :gender_male, :gender_female, :country, :state, :suburb, :postal ,:add are not able to save in the database....Please help and validation too

This is my user controller

```
def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:id])
    if @user.save
    session[:user_id]= @user.id
      redirect_to user_steps_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit( :fname, :lname, :email, :mob,  :gender_male, :gender_female, :country, :state, :suburb, :postal ,:add, :cmpyname, :abnacn, :cmpyadd, :cmpydet,:cash, :paypal,:bsb,:usrname, :password, :password_confirmation, :selcat, :protit, :prodes)
  end
```

This is my user_steps controller

```
 include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :business, :login, :payment



def show
  @user = current_user
  render_wizard
end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      render_wizard @user
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit( :fname, :lname, :email, :mob, :gender_male, :gender_female, :country, :state, :suburb, :postal ,:add, :cmpyname, :abnacn, :cmpyadd, :cmpydet,:cash, :paypal,:bsb,:usrname, :password, :password_confirmation, :selcat, :protit, :prodes)
  end
```

my migration table

```
 class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :fname
      t.string :lname
      t.string :email
      t.string :mob
      t.string :gender_male
      t.string :gender_female
      t.string :country
      t.string :state
      t.string :suburb
      t.string :postal
      t.string :add
      t.string :cmpyname
      t.string :abnacn
      t.string :cmpyadd
      t.string :cmpydet
      t.string :cash
      t.string :paypal
      t.string :bsb
      t.string :usrname
      t.string :password_hash
      t.string :password_salt
      t.string :selcat
      t.string :protit
      t.string :prodes
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wicked gem has been explained here by Ryan Bates
http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?view=asciicast

Comment: please dont vote me down this is my first question and give some suggestions

Comment: but in that he has used attr accessible which is not used in rails 4

Comment: Thats rails 3 video, still it will give you idea of wicked gem..

Comment: Please add some screen shots of error, your model code  and logs if you have

Comment: With the fields name you are using for password, I guess you are using bcrypt gem add this line into your user model if you are using bcrypt
`has_secure_password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit create in your user_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:id])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id]= @user.id
      @user.update_attributes(user_params )
      redirect_to user_steps_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

This will add that data in your database

Comment: you can use gem 'client_side_validations' to give validations

Answer (score 1):

In your migration , you have taken password_hash and password_salt as fields and mentioned just password in your controller . Update the user_params method in your controller as follows -

```
 def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit( :fname, :lname, :email, :mob,:password_hash,:password_salt,  :gender_male, :gender_female, :country, :state, :suburb, :postal ,:add, :cmpyname, :abnacn, :cmpyadd, :cmpydet,:cash, :paypal,:bsb,:usrname, :selcat, :protit, :prodes)
 end
```

Also try to keep proper names for fields as it would help you in the long run .

Comment: yes now the error is not coming...but password fields are empty in the database

Comment: Also please do consider accepting the answer if it helped you solve your issue

Comment: That's a seperate issue and related to wicked . I suspect you need to change the user_params in your wicked controller too .

Comment: Follow the railscast on wicked as it has more detailed explanation , rest all remains the same in rails 3 and rails 4 .